# Why are my inline-block elements not aligning horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get all these links to line up perfectly in a 5 column grid using inline-block. However, it seems there is a very small - perhaps 1px - misalignment between the top row and the row below it and I wonder if anyone could enlighten me as to why this is happening. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HAv5Y/) with the code below.

HTML:

```
<div class="app-control-btns-wrp">  
    <a href='javascript:;' class="app-control-btns">Link1</a>
    <a href='javascript:;' class="app-control-btns">Link2</a>
    <a href='javascript:;' class="app-control-btns">Link3</a>
    <a href='javascript:;' class="app-control-btns">Link4</a>
</div>

<div class='char-input-btns-wrp'>

    <div class='rows' >
        <a href='javascript:;' class="char-input-btns">A</a>
        <a href='javascript:;' class="char-input-btns">B</a>
        <a href='javascript:;' class="char-input-btns">C</a>
        <a href='javascript:;' class="char-input-btns">D</a>
        <a href='javascript:;' class="char-input-btns">E</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS (reset file included):

```
/*
    HTML5 Reset :: style.css
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    We have learned much from/been inspired by/taken code where offered from:

    Eric Meyer                  :: http://meyerweb.com
    HTML5 Doctor                :: http://html5doctor.com
    and the HTML5 Boilerplate   :: http://html5boilerplate.com

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* Let's default this puppy out
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

html, body, body div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, figure, footer, header, menu, nav, section, time, mark, audio, video, details, summary {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}                                   

/* consider resetting the default cursor: https://gist.github.com/murtaugh/5247154 */

article, aside, figure, footer, header, nav, section, details, summary {display: block;}

/* Responsive images and other embedded objects
   Note: keeping IMG here will cause problems if you're using foreground images as sprites.
   If this default setting for images is causing issues, you might want to replace it with a .responsive class instead. */
img,
object,
embed {max-width: 100%;}

/* force a vertical scrollbar to prevent a jumpy page */
html {overflow-y: scroll;}

/* we use a lot of ULs that aren't bulleted. 
    don't forget to restore the bullets within content. */
ul {list-style: none;}

blockquote, q {quotes: none;}

blockquote:before, 
blockquote:after, 
q:before, 
q:after {content: ''; content: none;}

a {margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 100%; vertical-align: baseline; background: transparent;}

del {text-decoration: line-through;}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; cursor: help;}

/* tables still need cellspacing="0" in the markup */
table {border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}
th {font-weight: bold; vertical-align: bottom;}
td {font-weight: normal; vertical-align: top;}

hr {display: block; height: 1px; border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 1em 0; padding: 0;}

input, select {vertical-align: middle;}

pre {
    white-space: pre; /* CSS2 */
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: pre-line; /* CSS 3 (and 2.1 as well, actually) */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* IE */
}

input[type="radio"] {vertical-align: text-bottom;}
input[type="checkbox"] {vertical-align: bottom;}
.ie7 input[type="checkbox"] {vertical-align: baseline;}
.ie6 input {vertical-align: text-bottom;}

select, input, textarea {font: 99% sans-serif;}

table {font-size: inherit; font: 100%;}

small {font-size: 85%;}

strong {font-weight: bold;}

td, td img {vertical-align: top;} 

/* Make sure sup and sub don't screw with your line-heights
    gist.github.com/413930 */
sub, sup {font-size: 75%; line-height: 0; position: relative;}
sup {top: -0.5em;}
sub {bottom: -0.25em;}

/* standardize any monospaced elements */
pre, code, kbd, samp {font-family: monospace, sans-serif;}

/* hand cursor on clickable elements */
.clickable,
label, 
input[type=button], 
input[type=submit], 
input[type=file], 
button {cursor: pointer;}

/* Webkit browsers add a 2px margin outside the chrome of form elements */
button, input, select, textarea {margin: 0;}

/* make buttons play nice in IE */
button,
input[type=button] {width: auto; overflow: visible;}

/* scale images in IE7 more attractively */
.ie7 img {-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}

/* prevent BG image flicker upon hover 
   (commented out as usage is rare, and the filter syntax messes with some pre-processors)
.ie6 html {filter: expression(document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true));}
*/

/* let's clear some floats */
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }  
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }  
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }  


*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.app-wrp{
    border:1px solid grey;
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid grey;
    margin:1em auto;
}

.app-header{
    width:100%;
    padding:1em;
    border-bottom:1px solid grey;
    background: #ccc;
}

.app-body{

}

#word{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    padding:3em 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid grey;
}

#word > p{
    font-size:3em;
    line-height:1.3em;
}



.char-input-btns-wrp, .app-control-btns-wrp{
    width:100%;
}

.app-control-btns-wrp{
    border-bottom:1px solid grey;
}

.char-input-btns, .app-control-btns{
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:2em;
    margin-right:-4px;
}

.app-control-btns{
    border-right:1px solid grey;    
    width:20%;
}

.app-control-btns:last-child{
    border-right:none;      
    width:40%;
}

.char-input-btns{
    width:20%;

    border-left: 1px solid grey;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    color: #424242;
    background:yellow;
}

.char-input-btns:active{
    background:#3399bb;
    color:#fff;
}

.char-input-btns:last-child{
    border-right: 0;
}

.char-input-btns:first-child{
    border-left: 0;
}

.rows{
    width:100%;
    background:pink;
}
```

Comment: If you'll only have textual data, why not use `table` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving border-left use border-right for your char-input-btns class. Update the following class

```
.char-input-btns{
width:20%;
border-right: 1px solid grey;
border-top: 1px solid grey;
color: #424242;
background:yellow;
 }
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HAv5Y/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Your elements don't have the same border rules. Your top row uses `border-right`, while your bottom row uses `border-top` and `border-left`. Because you have `box-sizing:border-box` as well, this means the result is offset by one.

Use consistent borders for a consistent result.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something dumb.